# How to prove site has been unaltered

Tags: hash, cryptography, proof

I have a simple site. It's one html page, and just plain text entries. The HTML is like this...

```
<div class='box'>

      April 15, 2021
      Today, I got a cat.

</div>

<div class='box'>

     April 16, 2021
     Today, I named the cat toby and fed him fish.

</div>
```

Is there a way to prove through some type of hash, that the entries have been unaltered? Like a way to prove that I never went back and changed one of the entries?

Comment: Did you mean an integrity check for visitors? You could do something like a HTTP Integrity header https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-hallambaker-httpintegrity-02.html

Comment: @sinkmanu no, i mean a proof that the contents have been unaltered since the last date. something like a blockchain maybe?

Comment: With an integrity check you can demonstrate that the file has not been changed

Comment: @sinkmanu I think you're looking at the validity of data in transit. Im trying to verify a unaltered document compared against yesterday. like how git tracks code, but this would just track journal entries.

Comment: No. Integrity is the way to demonstrate that a file has not been modified. E.g. You create a hash of the file yesterday and if today, the hash has been changed, the file has been modified